# How does the Google Cloud Compute Engine sustained use discount work?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

The documentation says "When you use an instance for more than 25% of a month, Compute Engine automatically gives you a discount for every incremental minute you use for that instance."

What does "when you use" mean here? Is it that the instance should be powered on? Some CPU usage threshold?

If I run an instance 24x7 but at little or no load, does it qualify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is referring to when the instance is powered on.

Comment: This is not a technical question regarding the GCS and as such has no place here.